# Android - Custom view showing black screen

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a custom view here but unfortunately it is showing a black screen.

My xml file "tester1"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<view
    class="pap.crowslanding.GameView"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</view>
</LinearLayout>
```

My activity which uses the layout seems fine

```
package pap.crowslanding;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Game extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.tester1);

    //GameView gameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);

}
}
```

And finally, the GameView activity which is not displaying properly

```
package pap.crowslanding;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;


public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
static final long FPS = 10;
public Bitmap bmp;
public SurfaceHolder holder;
public LoopGameThread loopGameThread;
public Sprite sprite;
public LayoutInflater inflater;


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    loopGameThread = new LoopGameThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            loopGameThread.isStart(true);
            loopGameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

    });
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.crow);
    sprite = new Sprite(this, bmp);
}
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);

}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for reading

EDIT:

this is the onDraw() of my Sprite

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();

    int srcX = currentFrame * width;
    int srcY = direction * height;

    src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
    dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
}
```

the sprite and the GameView worked before I implemented my Custom Layout unfortunately.

Comment: Your onDraw function is drawing a black screen, then trying to draw a sprite.  So what is your sprite onDraw doing?  Also, normally you define a custom view with <classname> rather than <view class=classname>, but I doubt that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I found the fix and it should have been obvious & incase anyone has my problem, here is the fix.

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO
}
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    //PUT YOUR CODE IN HERE
}
```

My problem was I was placing the code within context, context and im a newbie so I cannot explain it, perhaps because it is at the bottom so (context attrs) it is initialized last and overriding the others I don't know.

Perhaps someone can comment and enlighten everyone and myself on what I did.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the way you're trying to include the view:

```
<view
    class="pap.crowslanding.GameView"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</view>
```

This should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.mypackage.pap.crowslanding.GameView // <--replace with fully qualified class name
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem. I just get a black screen when I do this.